# es6 rename keys in object array

Tags: javascript

I have a sample array

```
const countries = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Albania"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Algeria"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "American Samoa"}
];
```

How can i change the keys from **id** and **name** to **label** and **value** like this in es6?

```
const countries = [
    {"label": 1, "value": "Afghanistan"},
    {"label": 2, "value": "Albania"},
    {"label": 3, "value": "Algeria"},
    {"label": 4, "value": "American Samoa"}
];
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another, and destructure the arguments for the least syntax noise:

```js
const countries = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Albania"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Algeria"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "American Samoa"}
];
const transformed = countries.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: id, value: name }));
console.log(transformed);
```

You could also transform to the new property names in the arguments themselves, if you wanted:

```js
const countries = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Albania"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Algeria"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "American Samoa"}
];
const transformed = countries.map(({ id: label, name: value }) => ({ label, value }));
console.log(transformed);
```